# How to fill an invisible/empty icon in unity launcher that appeared while trying to dock a launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, dock

A couple of days ago I was attempting to add an application to the unity launcher from the unity dash and instead of adding the app it created an "empty icon"(blank space) in the launcher there is no way to remove it right clicking produces nothing, hovering over the "icon" does not produce a tool tip, and clicking it does not open an application.  The only thing I can do with it is move it around in the stack of apps in the launcher.

Anyone know how to fix this?

[image: See Picture]

Comment: Try clicking the icon for a few seconds and a menu will pop up, with the option to delete the app from launcher.

Answer (score 7):

If I glitch my launcher and add one myself, I can remove it by restarting Unity.

You can restart it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing in `unity` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or clicking on the result labeled "unity".

The desktop should flicker for a moment, then it should come back up and the empty space should be gone.

Comment: This worked for me, but logged me out also. So first save all valuable information in open applications.

Comment: This will shut down some apps. For example, Google Chrome. But it works!